# Can I split the word according to condition in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to split the same word that start with letter م into two words , for ex معجبني split to ما عجبني how can i do that?? i m using python 2.7

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
token=u'معجبني'
if token[0]==u'م':
    token="i want her prosess to split the word into ما عجبني
```

the ouput that i want
ما عجبني
i hope any one help me

Comment: Do you mind giving an English example, since I believe this is the same for English

Comment: ok i mean for ex i have word x="nothing" if the word start with "no" then x=not thing (space between not and thing) i mean iit will be two word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `str.startswith()` to checks whether string starts with str, optionally restricting the matching with the given indices start and end.
You can do this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
token=u'معجبني'
new_t = token.replace(u'م',u'ما ',1) if token.startswith(u'م') else token
print(new_t)
#ما عجبني
```

Comment: Note that it only works for one word. A regex based solution would automatically scan the whole text.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) to replace the desired character with a space and other characters.

The `\\b` word boundary makes sure that `ﻡ` is the first character in the word. The word boundary [doesn't work well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/630924/6419007) with Python2.7 and UTF-8, so you could check if there's a space or string beginning before your character.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
token = u'ﻢﻌﺠﺒﻨﻳ'
#pattern = re.compile(u'\\bﻡ') # <- For Python3
pattern = re.compile(u'(\s|^)ﻡ') # <- For Python2.7
print(re.sub(pattern,u'ﻡﺍ ', token))
```

It outputs :

```
ما عجبني
```

The english equivalent would be :

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'\bno')
text = 'nothing something nothing anode'
print(re.sub(pattern,'not ', text))
# not thing something not thing anode
```

Note that it automatically checks every word in the text.

Comment: thank u but i have long text and i want to check each word if it start with م separate it and then make it as ما

Comment: @lina: Weird. It works on my computer. If I post it here and copy-paste it back, it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score -2):

Use the split method.

```
x = ‘blue,red,green’
x.split(“,”)

[‘blue’, ‘red’, ‘green’]
```

Taken from http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/dictionary/python-split

EDIT: You can then join the array with " ".join(arr). Or you could replace the desire letter with itself and a space.

You example: `nothing.replace("t", "t ") => "not thing"`